# Android creating calculator app

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to create a calculator app and I've been having problems with the xml layout.

Due to the amount of button even though I use dp's to determine the size of each button from screen to screen the result varies...

Am i supposed to create the layout in java so I can get the screen dimensions??  if so can I have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can design the layout file and then make a few versions of it with different sized buttons. put them in res/layout-small/, res/layout-large/, and res/layout-normal/. The system will pull the proper xml file according to what size display the device has.

Another option is to try to design the layout with specifying a size in dp, instead use `android:layout_weight` and `android:weightSum` to achieve the proportions you are wanting. Then it should scale itself based on the device without needing any different xml files.